# Make it clearer that “Strunk & White” doesn't account for edits on own posts, as it's done in “Copy Editor”'s description

Tags: feature-request, edits, badges, wording, edit-badges

In this picture, you can see the description of the badge "*Strunk & White*" and the badge "*Copy Editor*".

[image: badge tracker screenshot]

One description specifies that you don't get points if you edit your own posts. But for the other one, it's not specified.

Yet, both can only be earned if it's not our own posts. I think that it's more visible and understandable if the two descriptions are the same.

What do you think?

Comment: All I have to say is: I agree and I think everyone does.